# How to access parents's props value in vue component object?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to make two option groups with multiple limitations in element UI kit. In my case, i invoke a method as `@handleOptionClick` to prevent selection according to `multiple-limit` value. How can i access this `multiple-limit` in `handleGroupedOption` function ?

```
<el-select v-model="filterBy[filterKey]" @handleOptionClick="handleGroupedOption" placeholder="Filter By Incident" multiple>
    <el-option-group label="Select one" multiple-limit="1">
        <el-option
                v-for="(item, key, index) in makeList(mainTypes[filterKey])"
                v-if="index < 3"
                :label="item"
                :value="key">
        </el-option>
    </el-option-group>
    <el-option-group label="Select multiple" multiple-limit="0">
        <el-option
                v-for="(item, key, index) in makeList(mainTypes[filterKey])"
                v-if="index >= 3"
                :label="item"
                :value="key">
        </el-option>
    </el-option-group>
</el-select>


export default {
  methods: {
    handleGroupedOption (event) {
     console.log(event)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should pass the parents properties to the child.

Parent:

```html
    <template>
       <div class="parent">
           <my-child :mydata="mydata"></my-child>
       </div>
    </template>

    export default {
      data: function() {
        return { mydata: ["a", "b"] }
      }
    }
```

Child

```html
    <template>
       <div class="child">
           <div v-for="data in mydata">
              {{ data }}
           </div>
       </div>
    </template>

    export default {
      props: ['mydata']
    }
```

ANother options is ofcourse to access the parent directly in your chilcomponent via this.$parent

You could define a computed prop for this

```js
    computed {
      parentData: function() {
         return this.$parent.$data; // or whatever you want to access
      }
    }
```

Comment: I did not get you, can you please give me a fiddle for my case(for two group selection)?

Comment: well, can YOU give me a fiddle? If you expect a sample within a fiddle you should atleast provide a fiddle yourself.